# Как задать высоту в TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как задать нужную высоту в TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высота у однострочного `TextBox` зависит от размеров шрифта и вычисляется автоматически. В исходниках есть комментарий на тему того, что можно отключить `AutoSize` и менять высоту, однако согласно [**исходникам**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,257) это скрытое публичное свойство, унаследованное от `TextBoxBase`, которое не отображается ни в автокомплите, ни в редакторе свойств. Если его принудительно выставить в *.Designer.cs (), то это cработает только на время редактирования формы, после запуска дизайнер удалит вашу запись из своего файла все вернется в исходное состояние, хотя в режиме редактирования формы `TextBox` все еще будет делать вид "послушного мальчика" менять свои размеры, но только во время редактирования.

**Обходные пути:**

***В визуальном редакторе:***

1. Можете попытаться подобрать шрифт нужного размера, но выставить размер с точностью до пикселя не выйдет.
2. Если хочется быстро и наглядно - можно положить `TextBox` на `Panel`. Выставить `Border = None` у `TextBox` и `Border = Fixed3d` у `Panel`. А также заменить цвет фона `Panel` с дефолтного `Control` на `Window`. Получится такой составной контрол, который выглядит как `TextBox`. Этот вариант также поможет, если нужно выставить позицию ввода текста в положение, отличное от левого верхнего угла.

***В коде:***

3. Можете настроить параметры `TextBox`, включая скрытое свойство `AutoSize` полностью в коде, разумеется такой вариант исключает возможность предварительного просмотра в редакторе форм.
4. Можете создать класс унаследованный от `TextBox` и либо переопределить свойство `AutoSize` и сделать его видимым (оно виртуальное и скрыто атрибутами [**см. тут**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,255)), либо определить конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров) и просто выставить его в конструкторе в `false` и менять размер как нравится даже в редакторе форм.

**PS:** В формах еще много  таких не очевидных сюрпризов, некоторые решаются, некоторые нет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Воспользовался 4 вариантом. Второй вариант интересен выставлением позиции начала ввода текста, но все же остановился на последнем варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно свойство AutoSize у TextBox установить в false. Можно наследоваться от класса TextBox.

```
 public class TextBoxWithHeight : TextBox 
    {
        public bool Auto_Size
        {
            get { return this.AutoSize; }
            set { this.AutoSize = value; }
        }
    }
```

Или же в дизайнере добавить код

```
textBox.AutoSize = false;
textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
```

Так же можете попробовать изменить размер после того, как выставив свойство Multiline = true

Comment: multiLine как вариант не подходит.

Comment: @Александр Пузанов Всмысле для вашей задачи не подходит? А выше описанные варианты?

Comment: про дизайнер написал выше, там не все так просто

Answer (score 1):

Из резметки

```
<TextBox Height="45" />
```

или из кода

```
var textBox = new TextBox { Height = 45 };
```

Comment: в winforms нет разметки, видимо перепутали с wpf

Comment: Да, не заметил тега.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню у элемента [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) высота зависит от того, сколько в него строк умещается, иными словами, есть у него свойство [`Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx), его Вам нужно выставить в `true`, чтобы Ваш `TextBox` был высотой в несколько строк. Из кода это делается не сложно.

### Первый вариант:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true; 
textBox1.Height = 32;
```

И после этого Вы сможете менять уже высоту.

---

Однако, если Вы хотите оставить одну строку, при этом чтобы текст был больше - Вам нужно менять размер шрифта [`Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.font(v=vs.110).aspx) в текстовом поле у Вашего `TextBox`.

### Второй вариант:

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, 32);
```

---

То есть все зависит от того, что Вы хотите увидеть, если несколько строк того же размера, что и раньше - Вам по первому пути, если бОльший текст - меняйте размер шрифта. 
Можно менять как программным кодом, так и через свойства компонента в визуальном интерфейсе среды разработки.